# How to allow CORS with Node.js (without using Express)

Tags: javascript, node.js

I tried answers from other questions and used (updated from https://gist.github.com/balupton/3696140):

```
var http = require('http');
var cors = require('cors');

http.createServer(app).listen(3000).use();

function app(request, response) {

response.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
response.setHeader('Access-Control-Request-Method', '*');
response.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'OPTIONS, GET');
response.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', '*');

...

}
```

It returns: `http.createServer(...).listen(...).use is not a function`

After the update it runs but I am still getting 405 error on the client side.

Comment: Correct, `use` is not a method of `server` - perhaps [this](https://gist.github.com/balupton/3696140) will shed some light - seeing as node `cors` is middleware for Express (or Connect) - it's not surprising your code won't work as is

Comment: @JaromandaX https://gist.github.com/balupton/3696140 failed to work

Comment: You did it wrong

Comment: still getting the same error I bet ... seeing as you still do `http.createServer(app).listen(3000).use(cors());` ... derp

Comment: @JaromandaX oh just didn't update here. I am getting 405 error now.

Comment: show the client request in the question

Comment: FYI - the server does not need to send `Access-Control-Request-Method` - that is part of the preflight client request headers - yes, I know the thing you linked to issues that header, but really, if you want to learn about CORS, learn from [reliable documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS) - not from other numpties on the interwebs :p

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is because you are requesting a not-so-simple request, meaning it needs to handle preflight request which is made as an **HTTP OPTIONS** request (so **be sure your server is able to respond to this method**). The preflight request is a way of asking permissions for the actual request, before making the actual request. The server should inspect the two headers above to verify that both the HTTP method and the requested headers are valid and accepted.

Answer (score 48):

Here's a detailed answer to add CORS without plugins: The code has been taken from [here.](https://bigcodenerd.org/enable-cors-node-js-without-express/)
Read about CORS Security [here.](https://www.secureideas.com/blog/2018/07/three-c-words-of-web-app-security-part-1-cors.html)

```js
const http = require('http');
const port = 8080;

http.createServer((req, res) => {
  const headers = {
    'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*', /* @dev First, read about security */
    'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'OPTIONS, POST, GET',
    'Access-Control-Max-Age': 2592000, // 30 days
    /** add other headers as per requirement */
  };

  if (req.method === 'OPTIONS') {
    res.writeHead(204, headers);
    res.end();
    return;
  }

  if (['GET', 'POST'].indexOf(req.method) > -1) {
    res.writeHead(200, headers);
    res.end('Hello World');
    return;
  }

  res.writeHead(405, headers);
  res.end(`${req.method} is not allowed for the request.`);
}).listen(port);
```

```js
// You can also set using the following method
res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*'); /* @dev First, read about security */
res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'OPTIONS, GET');
res.setHeader('Access-Control-Max-Age', 2592000); // 30 days
res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'content-type'); // Might be helpful
```

Comment: This didn't work for me until '''res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', req.header.origin);'''according this: https://gist.github.com/balupton/3696140 '*' is not permitted for the Access-Control-Allow-Headers header.

Comment: I also had to add `res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'content-type');` as well. Some requests seem more tightly controlled.

Comment: Updated @treejanitor 

Answer (score 11):

No need to pass it to .writeHead(), these days you can use:

```
response.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
response.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'OPTIONS, GET');
response.setHeader('Access-Control-Max-Age', 2592000); // 30 days
```

Answer (score 6):

You don't want to use Express but yet trying to use it's middle-ware mechanism.

if

```
var server = http.createServer(app).listen(3000)
```

then server doesn't have the `.use` function, the `cors` module was designed as a middle-ware which means you need to use Express/Connect in order to use it.

You can keep being wihtout expressjs and find different ways than using `cors`, for e.g see here https://gist.github.com/balupton/3696140

Comment: For those looking everywhere and wondering why their manual solution still isn't working: The linked gist ended up working because it returns the CORS headers on both the preflight response and again on the actual response.