# How to add cors to a http server created for a websocket connection that is exposed on the same port as an express app?

Tags: node.js, express, http, websocket, cors

I am creating a backend with Node and express, with express I created a REST api, nothing complex, in the same server I created a websocket.io instance and the idea is to expose it on the same port as the express app, to do so I followed the method explained in here: [Express and WebSocket listening on the same port](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34808925/express-and-websocket-listening-on-the-same-port?newreg=31e7e28f218648fa99a6974f9d164a61) and it worked, the problem now is that the cors I set for the express app stopped working from the client once I wired the websocket to that same port, but if I make the requests from postman it works correctly.

I tried app.use(cors({origin:'*'}) but changed nothing, also in the initialization of the "io" constant, those cors solve the same issue but apparently it only worked for the websocket connection.

Also, I found that you can set the headers for an HTTP server passing an options object with the headers you want ([How to allow CORS with Node.js (without using Express)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44405448/how-to-allow-cors-with-node-js-without-using-express)), but in this case, the server is being created with an instance of an express app, so I am not sure how to solve it.

this is the code:

```
    const cors = require("cors");
    const express = require("express");
    const { createServer } = require("http");
    const userRoutes = require("./Users/routes");
    const itemRoutes = require("./Items/routes");
    
    const port = 3000;
    const app = express();
    
    app.use(cors());
    app.use(express.json());
    app.use("/api/v1/users", userRoutes);
    app.use("/api/v1/items", itemRoutes);
    
    const httpServer = createServer(app);
    
    console.log(app);
    
    httpServer.listen(port, () => {
      console.log(`App listening on port http://localhost:${port}`);
    });
    
    const io = require("socket.io")(httpServer, {
      cors: {
        origin: ["http://localhost:5173"],
      },
    });
    
    io.on("connection", (socket) => {
      console.log("a user connected");
    
      socket.on("disconnect", () => {
        console.log("user disconnected");
      });
    });
```

the idea is to being able to succesfully make requests from the client that as you might noticed is currently being exposed on http://localhost:5173

Answer (score 0):

I found that you can pass options to the express app as a middleware using express.static('public', options) where "options" is an object that can accept a lot of properties (https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#express.static) so what I did is:

```
const options = {
   setHeaders: (res, path, stat) => {
       res.set("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "http://localhost:5173");
   },
};

app.use(express.static("public", options));
```

and that did the trick!